# Check if Login is Done With Word or Office Applications in Custom Login

Tags: 2010, login

Hi, is there a way to check if the request to SharePoint comes from an Office application in a custom login page?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly. HTTP requests generated from Office clients are usually tagged with the user agent string, "Microsoft Office Existence Discovery".